# Prove that the infimum of half-open intervals contained in O is also in O

Tags: real-analysis

Let O be a non-empty open set. Let $x \in O$ and define $a_x = \inf \{a \in \mathbb{R} \mid (a, x] \subset O\}$. Prove that $(a_x, x] \subset O$.

The question seems pretty straightforward but I do not know how to clearly prove that the half-open interval of the infimum is also entirely contained in O. I know that $(a_x + \epsilon, x] \subset O$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ by definition of infimum. How can I conclude from here that also $(a_x, x] \subset O$ itself?

Comment: I edited this for proper use of \mid, and the difference is visible.  I also put in a proper use of \inf, and that becomes quite visible in expressions like $a\inf b$, which appears as $a\text{inf}b$ if \text{inf} is used instead of \inf, and in a "displayed" context, a\inf_{c\in C} b appears as $\displaystyle a\inf_{c\in C}b$, and that doesn't happen with \text{inf}. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y\in(a_x,x]$. If $y=x$, then clearly $y\in O$. If not, then $y\in(a_x,x-\varepsilon)$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Hence there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|y-z|<\delta$ implies $z\in(a_x,x-\varepsilon)$. Therefore $y\in(y-\delta, y+\delta)\subset (y,x]\subset O$, and as $y-\delta>a_x$, it follows by the definition of infimum that $y\in O$.